# Istanbul with webpack, getting `require.context` is `undefined` 

Tags: webpack, karma-runner, istanbul, webpack-style-loader, isparta

When using [karma-webpack](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/karma-webpack#alternative-usage) and [istanbul-instrumenter-loader](https://github.com/deepsweet/istanbul-instrumenter-loader) or [isparta-loader](https://github.com/deepsweet/isparta-loader), I get an error when attempting to implement it.

`require.context` comes up as `undefined`.

I believe this is because it is using/finding `nodejs` require and NOT webpack, as `Object.keys(require)` logs as `['keys', 'resolve', 'id']`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `require.context` is working, but `require` alone would use `node`. This may have something to do with the way that webpack doesn’t always treat object syntax as an actual object.

Therefore `require` has nothing to do with `require.context`. It is likely a regex function replace during build-time.